# Is there any advantages of assigning (bool) false to a variable

Tags: php

This is code from ADO DB. As you can see `false` is assigned to a variable `$false`.

```
    $false = false;

    if ($rows === false) {  
        return $false;
    }


    if (!class_exists($class)) {
        $db->outp_throw("Unknown class $class in GetActiveRecordsClass()",'GetActiveRecordsClass');
        return $false;
    }
```

Why do they do that?

To the person who has flagged my question as "primarly opinion based": I'm just looking for more "programming" reason of doing this. I'm not that expirienced programmer and I don't know many stuffs about PHP.

Is there any way that, for example, FALSE is an object and when you ASSIGN it to a variable and save its value to it, PHP creates space in the memory and it can be reused many times. Because I've heard that some languages the "boolean"s are objects. (Python, Ruby, etc...)

And doing `$false = false;` to be some kind of optimization or something.

Comment: See this comment on php.net -- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#112190

Comment: A wild guess - they have a constant named `false` :-) Cannot see any reason for doing this, except maybe som coding standards the people behind ADO DB favours.

Comment: @AmalMurali - String consisting `only` zero is `FALSE` because PHP casts the variables. And it's not that big deal. Also I couldn't answer to my question with what you've provided as a link.

@davidkonrad - They cannot set it as constant, because `false` is a PHP reserved word.

Comment: @FakeHeal, you are right of course. Trying to be funny ;-)

Comment: Can you link to a bigger chunk of code where this is used? Seems entirely nonsensical to me. Maybe they're preparing for the case of PHP redefining the meaning of `false`. *"Ha, told you! __We__ just need to change a single variable to work around this...! Who's laughing __now__?!* ;)

Comment: Re *"is doing this some kind of optimization"*: No. `false` is `false` and only `false` in PHP. The author probably came from some other language and couldn't shake the habit. And/or doesn't know what he's doing.

Comment: I've just googled it. [Only a single result though](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=LjghyGmluJvgzFU5UeneHgpg3yo&cid=5NxwbpRqh-A&s=&browser=Default&fp=305797&mpundefined&projSelected=true#L0)

Comment: @YourCommonSense: looking at the [ADODB source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adodb/?source=dlp), they're really using it more then once

Comment: Looking at the source linked to by @YourCommon: yeah, the author doesn't know what he's doing. ;) `global`s galore is a very bad sign.

Comment: It may be some optimization based on esoteric knowledge of how PHP works under the hood, or it may very well be an _attempt_ at an optimization based on _incorrect assumptions_ of how PHP works under the hood. I would say this classifies as micro-optimization and when you're working in PHP (or any interpreted language, really), such efforts are not worth while. For that matter, they may be counter productive since, as far as I know, PHP only guarantees behavior, not implementation.

Comment: Well if you're looking for more reasoning and the question is put on hold as primarily opinion based this should give you a good pack of hints that what you're looking for is highly esoteric and not well discussed here on site. don't ask in the blue, at least not here on SO, this is not helpful. I can understand you wonder, but don't wonder too much about sh*t code. Use your own brain instead.

Comment: ***Hint:*** Check the revision history of that file. The smell you've got might reveal more if you understand how it came into there over time.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, there are no advantages.

Newbie programmers often overcomplicate their code with no reason.
Most likely it is the case.

"Cargo cult programmers" often develop strange habits and superstitions among themselves, because they learn not by understanding but by example. PHP users are *especially* prone to this habit. Say, a failed attempt to access an array value can be seen very often:

```
$array['$key'];
```

because they took quotes as a part of array syntax. Also, `include`  followed by a pair of braces can be found almost everywhere.

Another brilliant example is a `mysql_real_escape_string` used with mysqli(!) prepared statements.

So, I am sure this one of the same kind. Suppose one have a belief that only variables can be returned - so, they would create a variable for the only purpose of returning.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that programmer was a hardcore PowerShell programmer, see my answer

Comment: isn't PowerShell a relatively new thing?

Comment: V1 was released in 2006

Comment: Well, ADODB is a decade older I believe.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that comes to my mind, is that you can replace the `$false = false;` with some other assignment if you want this function to return different value than boolean false (say, you want it to return a string `'error'` then you'd do `$false = 'error';`)

That's a silly idea though.

Comment: Well, actually, I've seen many people using AdoDB and I assumed that it's a good library. So, your idea is more acceptable than that they are like "OH, I FORGOT HOW TO PROGRAM" __(ref: I forgot how to human)__

Comment: @Fake It may well be a *good library* in the sense that it works reliably and provides useful functionality. That doesn't mean its code needs to be great.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense and is not needed. Anyway, my theory is that the programmer is addicted to [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell). In PowerShell it is quite common to use `$true`/`$false`. See [Understanding Booleans in PowerShell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2286.understanding-booleans-in-powershell.aspx) and [Boolean Values and Operators](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx).